# How to make gradle test logs more concise ? (e.g. no "What went wrong" and no "Try" sections)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, tdd

I'm trying to make my `gradle test` logs as concise and useful as possible.

So far I have this :

```
> Task :test FAILED

CylinderVolumeCalculatorTest > should return a volume of PI when cylinder radius is 1 and height is 1() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
    Expecting:
     3.141592653589793
    to be equal to:
     6
    but was not.

1 test completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/egi/Projets/Sandboxes/Kotlin/testConfig/tryConfig/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

I would like to get rig of everything that is below the line `1 test completed, 1 failed` which is noise I don't need while doing TDD. Does anybody have an idea on how to do that ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.